# PHP - Split text into 140 character parts

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a long message into 140 long parts. If the message part is not the last one, I want to add 3 dots to the end of it.

I'm having problems with the for loop below - depending on the message length parts are missing and the last message gets 3 dots added too:

```
$length = count($message);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    if ($i == $length) {
        echo $message[$i];
    } else {
        echo $message[$i]."...";
    }

}
```

This is the complete code:

```
$themessage = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

function split_to_chunks($to,$text) {
    $total_length = (137 - strlen($to));
    $text_arr = explode(" ",$text);
    $i=0;
    $message[0]="";
    foreach ($text_arr as $word) {
        if ( strlen($message[$i] . $word . ' ') <= $total_length ) {
            if ($text_arr[count($text_arr)-1] == $word) {
                $message[$i] .= $word;
            } else {
                $message[$i] .= $word . ' ';
            }
        } else {
            $i++;
            if ($text_arr[count($text_arr)-1] == $word) {
                $message[$i] = $word;
            } else {
                $message[$i] = $word . ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    $length = count($message);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {

        if($i == $length) {
        echo $message[$i];
        } else {
        echo $message[$i]."...";
        }

    }
    return $message;
}

if (strlen(utf8_decode($themessage))<141) {
    echo "Send";
} else {
    split_to_chunks("",$themessage);
}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: try it with [chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) or [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: Your function is both echoing and returning a value. Is that right?

Comment: Your first loop is exceeding beyond the `$message` array boundary. You should use `$i < $length` instead.

Comment: of note here is that all chunks but the last are 137 characters we add three manually (the ellippses "..."), the last is up to 140

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it with [chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)

```
echo substr(chunk_split($themessage, 137, '...'), 0, -3);
```

To preserve full words just use [wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
echo wordwrap($themessage, 137, '...');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_slice` if there is more than 140 keys, otherwise print as it was

```
<?php
$themessage = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
$words = explode(' ', $themessage);

if (count($words) > 140)
{
    echo implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, 140)) . '...';
}
else
{
    echo $themessage;
}
?>
```

Unless you wanted 140 characters, not words - your example was not defining that clearly but your code gives two options. For that:

```
<?php
$themessage = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
if (strlen($themessage) > 140)
{
    echo preg_replace('/\s*[^\s]+$/', '...', substr($themessage, 0, 137));
}
else
{
    echo $themessage;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php). It allows you to pass a string and a length, and it returns an array of parts.

Andy is right that you need a little more code to solve the last item. That is, if you want to do it really nice. Many pieces of code would just split the string on 137 characters and add '...' after each of them, even if the last chunk is 1, 2 or 3 characters long, so it could be joined with the next to last item.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
<?php
function chunkify($str, $chunkSize, $postfix)
{
  $postfixLength = strlen($postfix);
  $chunks = str_split($str, $chunkSize - $postfixLength);
  $lastChunk = count($chunks) - 1;
  if ($lastChunk > 0 && strlen($chunks[$lastChunk] <= $postfixLength))
  {
    $chunks[--$lastChunk] .= array_pop($chunks);
  }

  for ($i = 0; $i < $lastChunk; $i++)
  {
    $chunks[$i] .= '...';
  }

  return $chunks;
}

var_dump(
  chunkify(
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
    6, // Make this 140.
    '...'));
```

Comment: does not solve the problem of splitting into irregular pieces - 137 characters or less, last can be up to 140

Comment: @AndyJones use printf or sprintf to process str_spilt is the best solution here so far IMO

Comment: sprintf argument `%'.-140s`

Comment: @AndyJones I've added a piece of code to demonstrate how you can use it. If you want to do it really nice, you could indeed check if the last item is smaller than the postfix (3 chars or less) you could combine it with the prior item. This code does that.

Answer (score -1):

How about recursion?

```
/**
 * Split a string into chunks
 * @return array(part, part, part, ...) The chunks of the message in an array
 */
function split_to_chunks($str) {
  // we're done
  if (strlen($str) <= 140) 
    return array($str);

  // otherwise recur by merging the first part with the result of the recursion
  return array_merge(array(substr($str, 0, 137).  "..."), 
                     split_to_chunks(substr($str, 137))); 
}
```

If you want to split on word boundaries, then find the index of the last space character in the chunk.

```
// splits on word boundaries
function split_to_chunks($str) {
  // we're done
  if (strlen($str) <= 140) 
    return array($str);

  $index = strrpos(substr($str, 0, 137), " ");
  if (!$index) $index = 137;
  return array_merge(array(substr($str, 0, $index).  "..."), 
                     split_to_chunks(substr($str, $index))); 
}
```

Comment: A recursive call to parse a string of unknow length is inefficient and riskful, not to mention unnecessary.

Comment: recursion is a bad idea for random length strings - its asking for a memory leak

Comment: @GolezTrol - do point out HOW it leaks memory. Also keep in mind the solution is only a piece of the problem. The question was not how to deal with strings of random length. As for recursion being unnecessary, I highly disagree - recursion offers a elegant and simple way to solve this problem.

Comment: @AndyJones  didn't say it leaks memory. I was more hinting towards stack overflows, which is a more common result of recursion that went too deep.

Comment: @goleztrol that's true and an important thing to consider when programming recursively

Comment: And many programming issues can easily be solved without recursion. Even classical demonstrations of recursive programming (like faculty calculation) are just as easy implemented using a loop.